# How to synchronize two listboxes elements with drag&drop?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

For example the User will Drag and Drop and Reposition 1 element in the same listbox, the index of said element will change, at the same time I want another listbox to reposition the element that was moved at that index to match the listbox element that was repositioned.

[image]

Example of the drag & drop operation that I want to process (I moved Brandon at Index 0 in ListBox1 and Credit automatically was moved to the same index as ListBox1 in Listbox2).

How can I do this either programmaticaly or in xaml?

Comment: Which language are you working in? You've tagged C# and VB.NET

Comment: VB.Net, but I use a converter to convert C# into VB.Net if needed, so anyone can give me a solution in their comfortable language :).

Answer (score 1):

[synchronize two listboxes elements with drag&drop?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59gSL.png)

Hello my friend
there are 2 listbox here in the following C# code. you can order the elements inside the first one then you will see the same result in the listBox 2

Note 1:>>>>

> listBox1.AllowDrop = true;  on Form Load

Note 2: this line >>>

> object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
> you have to pass a string

=====================================================

```
  private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
        string s = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
        DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

   

    private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = listBox1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        int index = this.listBox1.IndexFromPoint(point);
        if (index < 0) index = this.listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
        this.listBox1.Items.Remove(data);
        this.listBox1.Items.Insert(index, data);

       
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i]);
            }


    }

    private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
```